# Place ion-menu icon to the right side of the header

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm currently working with ionic side menu template and its working properly for me, I made the side menu to slide from the right which is also a good thing for me, but the issue is, the menu icon is left placed at the left side enough though the menu is pushing from the right.
Is there any solution around to make place the icon too at the right side of the header?

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" type="reveal" side="right" menuToggle="right" >
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>

<!-- Disable swipe-to-go-back because it's poor UX to combine STGB with side menus -->
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the page where you want to display the menu, you can place '[end](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toolbar/Toolbar/)' in the button tag, and it will place your menu to right.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle end>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: use the given snippet in the page where you want to display menu. Lets you want menu in TestPage.html, then place above code there.